# Javascript For Loops for rules

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and am having trouble with the following code.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) 
{ 
console.log (i);
}

if (i % 3) { 
    console.log("Fizz"); 
} 

else if (i % 5) { 
    console.log("Buzz"); 
} 

else (i % 3 && 5) { 
    console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
}
```

The instructions are:

For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.
Otherwise, just print out the number.

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your attempt?

Comment: Your if condition must be within the curly brackets of your loop

Comment: 1) **Post your code here.** 2) You may want to put your `if`s into your loop...

Comment: your if statements are outside the for loop

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if (!(num % 3) && !(num % 5)) {
        console.log('FizzBuzz');
    } else if (!(num % 3)) {
        console.log('Fizz');
    } else if (!(num % 5)) {
        console.log('Buzz');
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your conditional code inside the loop and use if instead of else-if for your last condition will be completed in first two if:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) 
{ 

    console.log (i);
    // make it readable
    if (i % 3 == 0) { 
        console.log("Fizz"); 
    }         
    if (i % 5 == 0) { 
        console.log("Buzz"); 
    }         
}
```

Comment: This will print `Fizz` and `Buzz` for numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, but the rule is to print `FizzBuzz`. `else if` is the way to go, here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(num % 3) && !(num % 5)) {
    alert('FizzBuzz');
} else if (!(num % 3)) {
    alert('Fizz');
} else if (!(num % 5)) {
    alert('Buzz');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) 
{
    if (i % 3 === 0  && i % 5 === 0) { 
        console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) { 
        console.log("Fizz"); 
    }else if (i % 5 === 0 ) { 
        console.log("Buzz"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <html>
          <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>


                for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
                          {

                   if(i%3===0 && i%5===0) 
    { console.log("FizzBuzz!"); }
     else if (i%3===0) { console.log("Fizz"); }
      else if (i%5===0) { console.log("Buzz"); } 
      else { console.log(i); }
            };

           </script> 
              </body>
               </html>
```